# AWS Route 53 Traffic Geolocation Policy Not Working as Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a traffic policy that is being run on a domain that states explicitly for North America to route traffic to a server in VA (i have all continents set for relive regions). I also have a default regional setting to also route to VA for any other users when DNS can not resolve the location.

One of my clients in Atlanta GA is calling the domain and we are seeing the dns resolve to endpoints specified for Europe, North America and Asia. It appears that the DNS ip address is changing randomly from US to Europe, to Asia (i have verified this by pinging the domain and seeing the endpoint ips for these regions).

How is a user in Atlanta GA, USA being routed to Asia and Europe regions given the aforementioned configuration? I assume if DNS can not resolve, then the default would be used. I have a few pics here:

[image]

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: It looks like you have a misconfiguration.  Geo-routing is not an exact science but you should not be getting multiple answers to requests sent from one place.  The behavior you describe suggests that all the possible answers are being returned in a round-robin fashon... but ping is a poor test.  You need `dig` or `nslookup` -- either of those tools may show that you are actually returning multiple answers to each DNS query.

Comment: BTW, a great way to check global DNS resolution is: https://cachecheck.opendns.com/

Comment: Rather than using a Traffic Policy via the visual editor, have you tried configuring this directly as Record Sets? Simply create 4 Record Sets with `Routing Policy = Geolocation`, all with the same DNS name but different locations. Worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

The geo location feature works on the IP address locattion. For example the IP address specified in your route 53 is 52.78.92.108. Check the location of that IP. So if your customer IP address belongs to Europe he will be routed to Europe. Check this location detectors this will give you a idea.

https://www.iplocation.net

[image]

Comment: so, using the image i added a moment ago to the post showing the policy, if a user in Europe hits the domain, they should be routed to ip ending in 141 correct?

Comment: Yes if the IP belongs to Europe he will be routed there.

Comment: so, my user is in GA, USA and getting routed to Seoul and Frankfurt; what could cause this?

Comment: I told you above it does not work according to the user location it works according to the IP address of the user. Ask your user his IP address and check its location in the link here www.iplocation.net you will get his actual location of the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we just found that adware/malware was intercepting the client's requests and directing thru a proxy. Windows was not showing a proxy, but the malware was transcribing the web links thru its proxy.

I am guessing the proxy is located in east Europe so proxy routing was likely correct. Once the user removed the malware all worked as expected.